# In Windows 7, what is meant by a "managed" network connection? An "unmanaged" one?

Tags: windows-7, lan, ethernet

As referred to by opening the "Network and Sharing Center" and by clicking through as shown in the illustration below:

[image: Navigation steps]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'Managed' network location refers to one where the computer is part of a domain.

Typically, computers that are part of a corporate network are members of a domain that is managed by one or more domain controllers. Applications may use this indication to attempt to discover and connect to corporate resources. Applications may also use this indication to apply policy or settings that are specific to the corporate network.

An 'Unmanaged' network location is by default logic, one where a computer isn't part of a domain. Each machine can have it's own set of rules, policy settings etc which can be entirely different from anything else on that network (there is no way of forcing adherence to a specific policy/ruleset).